# Suspending the execution of a remote process (C, Windows)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process, suspend

I can suspend a thread of another process by using SuspendThread(). Is there any way to also suspend the execution of that process altogether?
If yes, please post code.

Thanks.

PS:
Since you will ask "Why do you want to do this" I'll post it here.
I am dealing with legacy software that is not maintained anymore. I don't have access to the source code. Right now I need it to pause until a file is filled with data and then resume the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to suspend all threads of that process.

If you want to see actual code, check the sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx).

Comment: would that suspend the process itself? I tried suspending all thread but the main process is still active.

Comment: A process includes one or more threads that actually execute the code in the process (technically, processes don’t run, threads do).

Comment: If you read that article on Codeproject, note that "some programs are not well-written" includes a lot of well-written programs that happen to be using a mutex in an entirely legitimate way. Suspending is always a bit risky and awkward (though for your particular example, it is probably hard to find something much better).

Answer (score 0):

*> The only way is to suspend all threads of that process.*

No.
Use Undocumented Kernel apis (exported since NT 3.1) to suspend the Pid.

Comment: thanks for the comments, but just saying "use undocumented API" won't give me any answer. If you know of any undocumented API please post it and give some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If the process has or spawns many threads rapidly or asynchronously, your subject to a race condition with SuspendThread().

A way to accomplish the same thing (that is process wide) is to attach as a debugger to the target process with [DebugActiveProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679295%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then simply call [DebugBreakProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679298%28VS.85%29.aspx).  When a process is at a break point, no new threads will be created and all execution, *process wide* will stop.